# npm modules not installing properly

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I have a `nodejs` project which i created months ago and abandon it. At that time it was working fine.

Now i have need that project but nodejs modules are not installing properly(as i expect). saying something

I am using following modules

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var five = require("johnny-five");
```

I first tried installing `npm install johnny-five` in my working directory(locally) and it gave me this error

```
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:78:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:82:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:93:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  jacobrosenthal/node-pre-gyp-github#production resetting remote C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-jacobrosenthal-node-pre-gyp-github-git-production-00f1b2658a8ab0261b1b6e8aa994ae37 because of error: { [Error: not found: git] code: 'ENOGIT' }
```

so i run `npm install -g twitter` & `npm install -g johnny-five`. It installed node_modules in following directory `C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

But when i run my programm `node execute.js` it gives me errors missing modules

I checked that modules i am using are installed

I recieved error for `request` module so i installed it then it gave me error for `serialport` and now this module is not installing

> I tried re-installing (after manually deleting johnny-five module folder)

It does install but also gives bunch of warning & errors

```
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:78:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:82:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:93:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  jacobrosenthal/node-pre-gyp-github#production resetting remote C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-jacobrosenthal-node-pre-gyp-github-git-production-00f1b2658a8ab0261b1b6e8aa994ae37 because of error: { [Error: not found: git] code: 'ENOGIT' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/jacobrosenthal/node-pre-gyp-github.git C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-jacobrosenthal-node-pre-gyp-github-git-production-00f1b2658a8ab0261b1b6e8aa994ae37: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/jacobrosenthal/node-pre-gyp-github.git C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-jacobrosenthal-node-pre-gyp-github-git-production-00f1b2658a8ab0261b1b6e8aa994ae37: undefined
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:78:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:82:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:93:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  jacobrosenthal/node-pre-gyp-github#production resetting remote C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-jacobrosenthal-node-pre-gyp-github-git-production-1e8dd7eab6415a0b31fc9e88e23213e9 because of error: { [Error: not found: git] code: 'ENOGIT' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/jacobrosenthal/node-pre-gyp-github.git C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-jacobrosenthal-node-pre-gyp-github-git-production-1e8dd7eab6415a0b31fc9e88e23213e9: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/jacobrosenthal/node-pre-gyp-github.git C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-jacobrosenthal-node-pre-gyp-github-git-production-1e8dd7eab6415a0b31fc9e88e23213e9: undefined
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:78:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:82:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:93:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  jacobrosenthal/node-pre-gyp-github#production resetting remote C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-jacobrosenthal-node-pre-gyp-github-git-production-d32d5d69965585ea64fc38a162bde390 because of error: { [Error: not found: git] code: 'ENOGIT' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:jacobrosenthal/node-pre-gyp-github.git C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-jacobrosenthal-node-pre-gyp-github-git-production-d32d5d69965585ea64fc38a162bde390: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:jacobrosenthal/node-pre-gyp-github.git C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-jacobrosenthal-node-pre-gyp-github-git-production-d32d5d69965585ea64fc38a162bde390: undefined
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: not found: git
C:\Users\skyse\AppData\Roaming\npm
└─┬ johnny-five@0.9.11
  ├─┬ array-includes@3.0.1
  │ ├─┬ define-properties@1.1.2
  │ │ ├── foreach@2.0.5
  │ │ └── object-keys@1.0.9
  │ └─┬ es-abstract@1.4.3
  │   ├─┬ es-to-primitive@1.0.0
  │   │ ├── is-date-object@1.0.1
  │   │ └── is-symbol@1.0.1
  │   ├── function-bind@1.0.2
  │   ├── is-callable@1.1.0
  │   └── is-regex@1.0.3
  ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
  │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
  │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.3
  │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
  │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
  │ ├── strip-ansi@3.0.0
  │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
  ├── color-convert@0.5.3
  ├── descriptor@0.1.0
  ├── ease-component@1.0.0
  ├── es6-shim@0.33.13
  ├── lodash@3.10.1
  ├── nanotimer@0.3.10
  └── temporal@0.5.0
```

Comment: Do you have `git` installed and is it in your `PATH`?

Comment: I have git. Which path? When it was working few months ago i didn't have git then.

Answer (score 0):

I had `node_modules/`in my parent directory of working directory. It contain old and missing files which was causing the problem. I deleted it and now everything works fine